# Can't get my variables to line up horizontally

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to get my *lambdas* to line up horizontally in the equation system but I can't use any more `&` in `align`. I have no idea how to make that possible. I have put `&` everywhere where I wanted to align the rows.

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
&2 \cdot \lambda_1 + 1 \cdot \lambda_2 &= &4 \\
&1 \cdot \lambda_1 + 1 \cdot \lambda_2 &= &1 \\
-&1 \cdot \lambda_1 + 1 \cdot \lambda_2 &= -&5 \\
\end{cases} 
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alignment here is achieved by use of `\phantom`s only, to accommodate for the placement of a unary minus:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{cases}
    \phantom{-}2 \cdot \lambda_1 + 1 \cdot \lambda_2 = \phantom{-}4 \\
    \phantom{-}1 \cdot \lambda_1 + 1 \cdot \lambda_2 = \phantom{-}1 \\
    -1 \cdot \lambda_1 + 1 \cdot \lambda_2 = -5
  \end{cases} 
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way using `alignedat`. By the way, never use `align` for a single line display.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
 2 \cdot \lambda_1 + 1 \cdot \lambda_2 &={} &  4 \\
 1 \cdot \lambda_1 + 1 \cdot \lambda_2 &={} &  1 \\
-1 \cdot \lambda_1 + 1 \cdot \lambda_2 &={} & -5
\end{alignedat}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way with `autoaligne`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{autoaligne}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\{\,
\aavcoeff{1.5}
\autoaligne{
  2\cdot\lambda_1 + 1\cdot\lambda_2 =   4 \\
  1\cdot\lambda_1 + 1\cdot\lambda_2 =   1 \\
\-1\cdot\lambda_1 + 1\cdot\lambda_2 = \-5
}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input. What do you mean by 'single line display'? Is it like [this screen](http://www.meinberg.co.uk/images/products/du70.jpg)?

Comment: @Clone A math display is when you set one or more equations separately from the running text, typically centered. If there is just one formula (or several formulas, but on a single line), use `equation` and not `align`.